# Library for SVG path calculations

Tags: python, svg

I'm looking for a library with Python bindings that can do calculations on SVG paths, such as calculating the length, and finding the coordinates of a point on the paths (ie, say the coordinates of the point 24.4% the length of the path).

Is there something around already?

A C-library would be acceptable as well, as I can easily make my own Python bindings.

Comment: You may also [rewrite the path's into another syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988004/parse-svgpath-d-attribute) and use any existing path visualization tool.

Comment: @feeela: Sure, but that has to be a tool that can handle all the path types of SVG, which essentially means it's written for SVG anyway. But if you have any ideas, they are welcome.

Comment: The only thing that springs to mind is maybe look at Inkscape - I believe it's C++ - but, I've never looked at the code, so can't guarantee there'll be something that fits your needs. Although, I don't know the SVG format that well, I wouldn't have thought it would be impracticable to extract paths (just some XML queries?) and use existing computational libraries (take your pick!)

Comment: @JonClements: It's not that easy. Parsing SVG path data isn't magic, but even a major SVG library (librsvg) doesn't do a good job at it. Calculating the length requires rectifying the curve using numeric integration or straight-line approximation. Finding the point at a certain percentage is even more involved, so this is all but trivial. All this functionality is part of the standard SVG DOM that browsers implement, but I'm not aware of any Python or C library offering it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OK, so I wrote it, and released it as a library.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/svg.path

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Inkscape' (IMO the best SVG editor out there), looking at their source code,  and see how they do it - and possibly you can reuse their libraries (they have a embedded Python scripting engine too) without much rework.

Comment: Inkscape is written in C++, and extracting a standalone library from that isn't feasible for me.